# SharePoint 2013 - How to properly add meta data from a custom page layout

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I would like to add this specific line to my SharPoint pages...

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, width=1024, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=5.0, minimum-scale=0.25"/>
```

But do it from the custom page layout, not from the master template.  Is this possible?  Every time I add this line to my page layout and publish it, I do not see it on a production page.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can add the meta information through your custom page layout, by doing following:

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead">
    <!-- Add stuff here -->
</asp:Content>
```

where `PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead` will place additional content that needs to be within the `<head>` tag of the page.

Reference:

[Required Content Placeholders in SharePoint Masterpages](http://hazaa.com.au/blog/required-content-placeholders-in-sharepoint-masterpages/)

Comment: Thank you Arsalan for this!  But allow me to ask you one more question - how do we push it higher?  there appears to be multiple SharePoint script links and and a SharePoint theme <link> above it.  I want my meta tag as close to the top as possible.

Comment: @blachawk check your masterpage and see if there is any `contentplaceholder` at the top of header. Can you customize your masterpage?